# Rigidbody.MovePosition stops working mid game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is a strange behavior happening in my game.
The following is attached to game objects in my game:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);

}
```

For reasons unbeknownst to me, my objects just stop moving, after around 10 seconds.  I have to trigger some kind of physics action, like OnCollisionEnter, by a bomb, in order for the objects to start moving again.  I looked into the optimization of sleeping rigid bodies, but printing out if the objects are sleep is false.

What can I do to stop my object from stopping moving?

Comment: Is your GameObject's RigidBody isKinematic selected?

Comment: @VitorFigueredo nope, isKinematic  is off.  I need it off, because these object have gravity turned on, and I need them to stay on top of the ground.

Comment: OK, I'm trying to recreate your situation here, to see if I get the same problem. That's why I asked you. Are you using a 2D or 3D RigidBody?

Comment: @VitorFigueredo 3D.

Comment: There is no problem with your code. I've just tested here and everything is working as it should. Are this objects constantly moving? How they switch directions (if they do). How do they stop or are destroyed? Take a look if you are no disabling it. Also, if this is running under a fixed update. I would use `Debug.Log ();` right above your commands. Try with just one so you don't get confused if you notice that Debug.Log stopped printing your text message you might be setting disabling this object if the message continues but the player doesn't is your rigid body that's been affected somehow.

Comment: @VitorFigueredo I replicated the issue.  Please pull the MovePositionIssue.unitypackage from https://github.com/fscopel/Unity3D-Demos.  Don't select anything in the editor and run the game.  You will see that nothing happens.  Select the floor and you will see the car move.  Very weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've downloaded your .unitypackage and I think I might know what your problem is:

I've messed around with your RigidBody and Collider settings. Nothing seemed to solve the problem but I was noticing that the player was literally teleporting. That was weird, it seemed like the game was really laggy which is virtually impossible since you had just one GameObject. It seemed to me that was something code related. So I went to see how your EnemyScript.cs was written. I noticed you were using FixedUpdate AND Update. I would not recommend that because you are calling something every 0.02 seconds and something every frame end.

I've tried to take `rb.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);` out of `FixedUpdate` and add it to `Update` that didn't fixed the problem. But then I analyzed what you were doing in `Update ()`. `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, yRotation, 0);` This makes no sense to me. The code does but why you are using it doesn't make sense to me. So I commented the whole  `Update ()` section. Added 10 to max speed and 2 to min speed and done!

Your Kubelwagen is riding until the end of your platform. If I had to guess, your enemy was constantly trying to tuck into the ground and at some point, it succeeds, that's why it stopped. Please, tell me if this solves your problem.

Comment: That did the trick. I moved the rotation code to a more appropriate area, and got rid of the Update().  Thank you for taking the time to look at it. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @FabioS. If you want to move a Rigiodbody object, don't use the transform to move it. Use the Rigidbody functions such as `AddForce`, `velocity` and `MovePosition`. The same thing applies to rotation. Use `AddTorque` and `MoveRotation` etc. In your case, replace `transform.rotation` with `rbMoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, yRotation, 0));`

Comment: @Programmer I did not know about `rb.MoveRotation()` - Thank you

Comment: No problem. Solve this one is hard because that part of code is not in your question so it requires downloading it to find that. I suggest posting more code in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried keeping this code inside the 
        LateUpdate() 
method sometimes this solves too